# What does it mean to differentiate a map from $M_n$ to itself?

Tags: real-analysis

Here, $M_n$ is the space of real $n \times n$ matrices.

This is in the context of differentiating functions $f: U \to \mathbb{R}^m$ (with $U \subseteq \mathbb{R}^n$ open), where the derivative at a point $x \in U$, $D f(x)$, is a linear map $\mathbb{R}^n \to \mathbb{R}^m$ satisfying $\lim_{h \to 0} \frac{f(x + h) - f(x) - D f(x) h}{\|h\|} = 0$ (when it exists).

What's the corresponding derivative for a map $f: M_n \to M_n$ - presumably it's a linear map $M_n \to M_n$ that is somehow a linear approximation to $f$?

Do we just treat $M_n$ as $\mathbb{R}^{n^2}$, and if so is there a natural isomorphism to use?

Or do we somehow modify the definition above, taking $H \in M_n$ tending to the zero matrix? Under what norm on $M_n$?

---

For a concrete example, could take say $f(A) = 2A$ or $f(A) = A^2$.

Comment: Yes, we treat $M_n$ as $\mathbb{R}^{n^2}$. There's not a single natural isomorphism, the two choices to list the matrix entries row-wise or column-wise are both equally natural.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To study maps whose domain (and codomain) are spaces of matrices is not uncommon. 
This is sometimes called [Matrix Calculus](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matrix_calculus)

While for a finite-dimensional real vector-space all norms on it are equivalent and it thus does not matter that much it still can be useful to consider norms on the space of matrices that are tailored to the fact that one considers matrices (as opposed to some vector of size $n^2$); these are called [matrix norms](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matrix_norm). In particular, one might want to have some compatibility of the norm with matrix multiplication. Some sources call a norm on the vectorspace of matrices a matrix norm only if it also fulfills $$||AB|| \le ||A|| \  ||B||$$ in addition to the usual axiomas one has for an norm; this is not universal though. Anyway, special types of norms are considered for matrices, which are different from the ones that would be induced by using one of the common norms on $\mathbb{R}^{n^2}$.

Comment: Is the section of that Wikipedia article entitled [Other matrix derivatives](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matrix_calculus#Other_matrix_derivatives), in particular the expression for $\frac{\partial \mathbf{F}}{\partial \mathbf{X}}$, equivalent to the derivative that I'm considering? I'm not sure how to best describe the linear map which is the derivative of a map $f: M_n \to M_n$. The article mentions fourth-rank tensors: is this a good way?

Comment: Is there a way to formulate the derivative of a map whose domain is a matrix space directly in terms of matrices and such a norm (for example, the operator norm)? I'm thinking of something like $\lim_{H \to 0} \frac{f(X + H) - f(X) - D f(X) H}{\|H\|} = 0$, with $X, H \in M_n$.

Comment: See there "Relation to other derivatives: 
The matrix derivative is a convenient notation for keeping track of partial derivatives for doing calculations. The Fréchet derivative is the standard way in the setting of functional analysis to take derivatives with respect to vectors. In the case that a matrix function of a matrix is Fréchet differentiable, the two derivatives will agree up to translation of notations. As is the case in general for partial derivatives, some formulae may extend under weaker analytic conditions than the existence of the derivative as approximating linear mapping."

Comment: And, what you are considering  is exactly the Fréchet derivative. You can use this forumula. But be careful. An issue is what type of object is $Df(X)$ here. It will not be an element of $M_n$ since it must be an elemnt *from the space of linear maps from* $M_n$ to $M_n$ and this space has dimension $n^2 \times n^2$. This should be the "fourth rank tensor" mentioned in the section you quote.